# Troubles linking my watson studio with my github repo

Tags: github, repository, watson-studio

I cannot find a way to link my watson studio with github repo.
I followed these steps:

1. in watson studio I navigate to integrations and generate an access token.
2. I copy the string of 40 characters and pasted it in the box.
3. I navigate to my projects' settings and in the "integrations" section I added the address to    my repo from github.

All that done, when I try to share one of my jupyter notebooks i get the following error:

> "Se ha producido un error al publicar el notebook Vuelva a intentarlo
> más adelante."

in Spanish.
In english should be something like:

> "An error took place while publishing your notebook. Try again later."

There is no code, no reference, just try again later. This happens since 3 weeks, renewing the keys, redoing the accounts, etc.

I don't know where to find for further clues to find the problem.
Any help will be really appreciated since having troubles in something so basic is very annoying.

Best

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue is that github doesn't name the default branch as master anymore.
Watson Studio looks for this branch and if it doesn't find it gives the above error.

Creating a new branch named "master" and making it the default branch solved the issue.